# SqlCommand Query and iteration to execute data into multiple XML files with my given program

Tags: c#, sql, xml, sql-server-2008, download

I am writing a prototype to programmatically get video data from a database and use C# to place this data into an XML manifest file. Each video is an asset element inside XML, and I am querying all the data I need from a SQLCommand.

Problem: The XML file can only hold up to 100 video assets per file, and so I need to come up with an iterator that saves 100 assets per file until I reach the end row in the database. I am using while(r.Read()), a SqlDataReader to go into the data base using a SqlCommand.

I would like to know how to go about this process of appending 100 assets per file using a certain SQLCommand and an iteration inside the reader to process all files needed.

Below is my code thus far! (Clearly I am going to have to change some things around, such as the global elements of the XML file, which need to go in every XML file created)

```
        protected void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //On btn click, call method to execute program and save all files in local path
        GetVideoData();
    }

    protected void GetVideoData()
    {
        string preparer = "AgencyOasis";
        string type = "VIDEO_FULL";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(docNode);

        //add global elements:
        //create parameters for each attribute in root to be replaced, and append the new root tag to empty XML doc
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("publisher-upload-manifest");
        root.SetAttribute("publisher-id", tbPublisherID.Text);
        root.SetAttribute("preparer", preparer);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        //append notify as child to root, already in doc
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmail.Text)) {
            XmlElement notify = doc.CreateElement("notify");
            notify.SetAttribute("email", tbEmail.Text);
            root.AppendChild(notify);
        }

        //THE REST OF THE ELEMENTS ARE A UNIQUE CASE FOR EACH VIDEO, THEREFORE SHOULD LOOP INSIDE THE QUERY RESULT SET, PER VIDEO.

        string sql100 = "SELECT TOP 100 Location, VideoLibraryId, Title, Keywords, IsActive, Description FROM VideoLibrary";
        const string _connStringName = "SanfordVideosConnectionString";
        string dsn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connStringName].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dsn))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql100, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                //while going through each row with above SQL command, set data to element attributes in doc for each asset
                XmlElement asset = doc.CreateElement("asset");
                asset.SetAttribute("filename", r["Location"].ToString());
                asset.SetAttribute("refid", r["VideoLibraryId"].ToString());

                // TODO: NEED ACTUAL FILE LOCATION BEFORE I CAN EXTRACT THE SIZE OF THE FILE ITSELF
                /*create new FileInfo object to get length of existing video file
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(r["Location"].ToString());
                long f1 = f.Length;         */

                //asset.SetAttribute("size", "10");      // TODO: f1.ToString() for static value of 2nd @
                // TODO: NEED ACTUAL FILE LOCATION AGAIN FOR HASH-CODE
                //asset.SetAttribute("hash-code", "10");  //TODO: GetMD5Hash(r["Location"].ToString())
                //setting the type globally for all videos to VIDEO_FULL ensures FLV and MP4 formats
                asset.SetAttribute("type", type);
                root.AppendChild(asset);

                XmlElement title = doc.CreateElement("title");
                title.SetAttribute("name", r["Title"].ToString());
                title.SetAttribute("refid", r["VideoLibraryId"].ToString());
                title.SetAttribute("active", r["IsActive"].ToString().ToUpper());
                // TODO: CHECK TO SEE IF VIDEO-FULL-REFID IS CORRECT
                //title.SetAttribute("video-full-refid", r["Location"].ToString() + "-" + r["VideoLibraryId"].ToString());

                XmlElement shortDesc = doc.CreateElement("short-description");
                shortDesc.InnerText = GetTrimmedDescription(250, r["Description"].ToString());
                title.AppendChild(shortDesc);
                root.AppendChild(title);

                XmlElement longDesc = doc.CreateElement("long-description");
                longDesc.InnerText = GetTrimmedDescription(5000, r["Description"].ToString());
                title.AppendChild(longDesc);
                root.AppendChild(title);
            }

        }

        //TEMPORARY FILE SAVE LOCATION  TODO: SAVE MULTIPLE FILES IN LOCAL FOLDER
        //returns the directory from where the current application domain was loaded 
        //string xmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, inputFileName1);
        string xmlPath = Server.MapPath(txtBoxInput.Text);
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(xmlPath, null);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        doc.Save(xmlPath);
    }

    //Trims long and short descriptions to max size of chars depending on max size (250 for short and 5000 for long)
    public string GetTrimmedDescription(int maxLength, string desc) {

        if (desc.Length > maxLength)
        {
            return desc.Substring(0, (maxLength - 4)) + " ...";
        }
        else
        {
            return desc;
        }

    }
```

Feel free to ask me any questions about the program and I'll try my best to explain!

Comment: can you write a select Top 100 in your sql and pass a param as to where you are wanting to select it from..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE To be honest, I'm not sure how that even works. I just want to go through 100 assets at a time, load them into an XML file, and save that file, then move onto the next 100 assets. No particular order is needed, just an iteration. After reading this, if you think passing a param will still work most efficiently, could you please expand on your findings? Thanks Kraze

Comment: Could I use a SqlDataReader method to go about this? I would like to take a two step process approach by going right from the table into the XML files, instead of taking an intermediate step of populating arrays for each column, and then using an iterator to set attributes for each XML file. Any suggestions would be great..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I keep your code mostly as is, here is a possible solution.  I have added in some comments where I refactored pieces.

The general idea is to fetch everything (not just 100 records) and introduce  a counter that tracks where you are at.  Every 100 records you spit out the file and reset.  After you've read everything you have to spit out what is remaining.  Since there are multiple files created, you will also have to track that and use a different filename.  I just added a file suffix.  I think the code below should work for you.

```
    protected void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //On btn click, call method to execute program and save all files in local path
    GetVideoData();
}

protected void GetVideoData()
    {
        string type = "VIDEO_FULL";

        XmlDocument doc;
        XmlElement root;
        // Refactor document creation to its own function
        doc = CreateANewDoc();
        // Refactor root creation to its own function
        root = CreateANewRoot(doc);

        //THE REST OF THE ELEMENTS ARE A UNIQUE CASE FOR EACH VIDEO, THEREFORE SHOULD LOOP INSIDE THE QUERY RESULT SET, PER VIDEO.

        // remove the top 100 and fetch everything  
        string sql100 = "SELECT Location, VideoLibraryId, Title, Keywords, IsActive, Description FROM VideoLibrary";
        const string _connStringName = "SanfordVideosConnectionString";
        string dsn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connStringName].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dsn))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql100, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // declare some counters
            int counter = 0;
            int filecounter = 0;

            while (r.Read())
            {
                counter++; // Increment counter

                // when you hit 100, write stuff out and reset
                if (counter == 100 )
                {
                    filecounter++; // Increment filecounter
                    DumpOutFile(doc, filecounter);
                    // Reset counter
                    counter = 0;
                    // Reset doc
                    doc = CreateANewDoc();
                    root = CreateANewRoot(doc);
                }

                //while going through each row with above SQL command, set data to element attributes in doc for each asset
                XmlElement asset = doc.CreateElement("asset");
                asset.SetAttribute("filename", r["Location"].ToString());
                asset.SetAttribute("refid", r["VideoLibraryId"].ToString());

                // TODO: NEED ACTUAL FILE LOCATION BEFORE I CAN EXTRACT THE SIZE OF THE FILE ITSELF
                /*create new FileInfo object to get length of existing video file
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(r["Location"].ToString());
                long f1 = f.Length;         */

                //asset.SetAttribute("size", "10");      // TODO: f1.ToString() for static value of 2nd @
                // TODO: NEED ACTUAL FILE LOCATION AGAIN FOR HASH-CODE
                //asset.SetAttribute("hash-code", "10");  //TODO: GetMD5Hash(r["Location"].ToString())
                //setting the type globally for all videos to VIDEO_FULL ensures FLV and MP4 formats
                asset.SetAttribute("type", type);
                root.AppendChild(asset);

                XmlElement title = doc.CreateElement("title");
                title.SetAttribute("name", r["Title"].ToString());
                title.SetAttribute("refid", r["VideoLibraryId"].ToString());
                title.SetAttribute("active", r["IsActive"].ToString().ToUpper());
                // TODO: CHECK TO SEE IF VIDEO-FULL-REFID IS CORRECT
                //title.SetAttribute("video-full-refid", r["Location"].ToString() + "-" + r["VideoLibraryId"].ToString());

                XmlElement shortDesc = doc.CreateElement("short-description");
                shortDesc.InnerText = GetTrimmedDescription(250, r["Description"].ToString());
                title.AppendChild(shortDesc);
                root.AppendChild(title);

                XmlElement longDesc = doc.CreateElement("long-description");
                longDesc.InnerText = GetTrimmedDescription(5000, r["Description"].ToString());
                title.AppendChild(longDesc);
                root.AppendChild(title);

            }

            // Dump out whatever is left (handles the remainder after division by 100
            DumpOutFile(doc, filecounter + 1);
        }

    }

//Trims long and short descriptions to max size of chars depending on max size (250 for short and 5000 for long)
public string GetTrimmedDescription(int maxLength, string desc) {

    if (desc.Length > maxLength)
    {
        return desc.Substring(0, (maxLength - 4)) + " ...";
    }
    else
    {
        return desc;
    }

}

private XmlDocument CreateANewDoc()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    doc.AppendChild(docNode);
    return doc;
}

private XmlElement CreateANewRoot(XmlDocument doc)
{
    string preparer = "AgencyOasis";

    //add global elements:
    //create parameters for each attribute in root to be replaced, and append the new root tag to empty XML doc
    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("publisher-upload-manifest");
    //root.SetAttribute("publisher-id", tbPublisherID.Text);
    root.SetAttribute("publisher-id", "tbPublisherID.Text");
    root.SetAttribute("preparer", preparer);
    doc.AppendChild(root);

    //append notify as child to root, already in doc
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmail.Text)) {
        XmlElement notify = doc.CreateElement("notify");
        notify.SetAttribute("email", tbEmail.Text);
        root.AppendChild(notify);
    }

    return root;
}

private void DumpOutFile(XmlDocument doc, int filenumber)
{
    //TEMPORARY FILE SAVE LOCATION  TODO: SAVE MULTIPLE FILES IN LOCAL FOLDER
    //returns the directory from where the current application domain was loaded 
    //string xmlPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, inputFileName1);
    string xmlPath = Server.MapPath(txtBoxInput.Text + filenumber.ToString());
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(xmlPath, null);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(xmlPath);
}
```

Comment: I chose this as the best answer because you implemented my own code in a more effective manner. I wouldn't have created helper methods, mainly because it's something I have to progress into from the sloppy coding I  currently write, and so I appreciate your organization and willingness to take up my question into your own hands. I'll let you know if I make any small tweaks or if anything goes wrong! Thanks again Steven, your efforts are revealing :)